# FlatMap is not a function - Node 12+

Tags: javascript, node.js, hugo, nvm

I am currently trying to run Hugo on a Linux server but when I run the command I am getting the following error:

```
hugo
Start building sites …
WARN 2021/05/06 10:46:39 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomy": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2021/05/06 10:46:39 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomy": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
Total in 1968 ms
Error: Error building site: POSTCSS: failed to transform "css/main.css" (text/css): TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function
```

I thought it was my node version at first as I know FlatMap was added in V11 but I was running V12. I also updated to V16 just in case but the error still persists. Any ideas?

I have also removed the node_modules folder since changing the node version.

Thanks

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the code that is causing the error?

Comment: I am running the command "hugo" from https://gohugo.io

Comment: Please show and not tell

Comment: There's nothing to show... I'm literally running `hugo`

Comment: There should be right? Why is it complaining about `css/main.css`, maybe the issue is in there?

Comment: This runs locally fine. Just not on this server.

Comment: Maybe the server is adding those line endings?